# Nome cortado por CSS

Tags: bug, status-intencional, design, layout

Hoje encontrei esta resposta do Robson e reparei que o nome está cortado. Talvez porque a nossa cultura é generosa com os apelidos este problema surge mais facilmente aqui. (Nunca tinha reparado nele em outros sites SE).

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Assim a `<div>` `user-details` está a cortar o excesso da largura, e porque o `overflow`está escondido.

```
.user-info .user-details {

    float: left;
    margin-left: 5px;
    width: 145px;
    overflow: hidden;
    white-space: nowrap;
```

Como resolver?

Adaptar o CSS ou limitar o nome de utilizador em tamanho?

Comment: Na verdade esse problema já ocorre na versão inglesa do site: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/65606/long-names-cut-off-in-questions-and-answers

Comment: @EvandroSilva, bem visto. Eu deixo a pergunta estar aqui e acho que podias traduzir o link e pôr como resposta aqui. Assim todos ficam a saber essa regra dos 26 caracteres, em Português.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Existe uma quantidade limite de caracteres (26 para ser exato) permitidos pelo site, entretanto, devido à fonte não ser `monospace`, o tamanho da `div` não pode conter o texto exatamente, protanto:

*AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA*

representa um nome com 26 caracteres e

*IIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIII*

Também representa um nome com a mesma quantidade de caracteres, entretanto, como podemos notar, o tamanho dos nomes é totalmente diferente.

Fonte <sup>em Inglês</sup> [**aqui**](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/65606/long-names-cut-off-in-questions-and-answers).